# Unit Test takes so much time to be executed

Tags: java, spring, testing, junit, mockito

I have a spring-boot project with many unit tests using junit and mockito. For every time i execute the tests is takes so much time (30 min).So i think the solution is to use many thread to execute all tests. Is there a solution for changing the execution of tests from sequential execution to parallel execution using multithread ?

Comment: How many tests do you have?

Comment: Also, are those `@SpringBootTest`s? If so, try to remove the annotation where ever you can. Do you use `@ExtendsWith(MockitoExtension.class)`? If so: try removing this annotation (as well as all `@Mock`- and `@InjectMocks`-annotations, do the mocking and injection by hand). This should also improve execution time.

Comment: Check out https://junit.org/junit5/docs/snapshot/user-guide/ paragraph _2.19. Parallel Execution_ if you really want to execute them in parallel. Beware that this feature is still experimental in junit5 (and you probably can not parallelize every test case)

Comment: i have 600 tests and it takes approximately 30 min to run all of them. I am using junit toolbox to run the tests in parallel and now it's about 13 min. I am using junit4.

Comment: Turing85 How can i remove (@Mock and @InjectMock) and inject by hand ?